# the meaning of "developed"

Tags: grammar, adjective-phrases, participial-adjectives

I have learned something about adjective phrases and participle phrases.

We can't say:

> The window open in the fourth floor is broken.

Because "open in the fourth floor" is not an adjective phrase.

But if we say:

> The country developed in 1990s is my hometown

Here it means the country became a developed country or just made some progress?

Because if the participle is the predicative, I'm not sure if it should follow the same rule as the adjective does. "Be developed in 1990s" is not an adjective phrase, right?

Comment: _open in the fourth floor_ **is** an adjectival phrase, modifying _The window._ It would be better with _that is_ preceding the phrase, though.

Comment: A country can not be a hometown... "hometowns" specifically require city names. "Seattle is my hometown"... Never "The United States is my hometown".

Comment: We generally say *open **on** the fourth floor*, but sure, you can say that. Adjectives can take complements and locative adjuncts just as nouns and verbs can. Moreover, a participle **is** an adjective. It is also a verb. *At the same time*.

Comment: But open on the fouth floor is an adjective phrase?

Comment: It is both an adjective phrase (it's head is the adjective *open*) and an adjectival phrase (a phrase acting syntactically as an adjective: modifying a noun). Granted, *open* and *on the fourth floor* don't have to constitute a single phrase; as written it implies that *on the fourth floor* is where the window is open, but *the open window on the fourth floor* has **two** adjective phrases modifying *window*, *open* and *on the fourth floor*.

Comment: But what is the difference...The window opened on the fourth floor is broken. The window open on the fourth floor is broken... Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

You're sort of correct.  "in the fourth floor" is not an adjectival phrase.

"In the fourth floor", however, is an adverbial phrase.  It modifies the adjective "open."  You absolutely can say that correctly, and "open on the fourth floor" is absolutely a valid adjectival phrase.  It consists of an adjective and an adverbial phrase.

However, the preposition more commonly used with "on the X floor" is "on."

"The country developed in (the) 1990's" again has an adverbial phrase that begins with "in."

"The" is correct before 1990's because 1990's is a proper, count noun.  Ask yourself "how many 90's are there?"

If the answer is one, use "the".

If the answer is many, use "a".

If the answer is "that makes no sense, you can't count this thing," use no article before the word.

Edit: Transcription error, and then I wrote it in a confusing way.  Corrected with the help of the below.

Comment: See commentary above—your first sentence is incorrect here. _open in the fourth floor_ is an _adjectival phrase._ It modifies the noun _window._ It is also an _adjective phrase_ with _open_ at its head.

Comment: This is in the first place incorrect because the phrase "in the fourth floor" modifies "open", an adjective.  Serving to modify an adjective makes it by definition an adverbial phrase.

Second, your distinction between the meaning of Adjective and Adjectival is not attested to in Strunk and White or the Oxford English Grammar, and a quick Google search gives it no sources.  I don't believe the distinction you attempt to make exists.

Comment: See [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective_phrase#Adjective_phrase_vs._adjectival_phrase).

Comment: First, that's an unsourced portion of a wikipedia article.

Second, even if that distinction is real, "in the fourth floor" still is a phrase that is functioning as an adverb, not an adjective.  Adverbs modify adjectives, not other adjectives.

Comment: Further recommended reading is [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Adjective-Phrases.htm). Don't know why you can't find these, when I can! Certainly _in the fourth floor_ modifies the adjective _open._ The sole error is in the first statement, as @StoneyB would concur if he were interested. If you have need of an entertaining colloquy, I suggest that you engage him in the commentary above. (I'll bring the popcorn.)

Comment: Ah, I see now.  You are absolutely correct.  Open is an adjective and therefore it and the accompanying phrase are of course an adjectival phrase.  I did not mean to include open there.  Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: We are all students here! (The `edit` link under your answer is your friend.)

Comment: Thanks very much for your help！ I have learnt something. You can reduce but the phrase should be adjective phrase（adj+complement， in the fourth floor not a complement） So in this way，The country developed in the 1990s just means the country made some progress at that time， we can't know if it is a developed country or not from this sentence…Am I right？